# Creating a product page for each specific item

Tags: php, html

I am working on my first website using Html, CSS, JS, PHP etc. I want to create a product page where the buyer would view the products. Then, by clicking on the product the buyer would be redirected to the page of that product where all the information of the product will be displayed. My items are stored in a MySql database. My question is, do I have to create a separate page for each product? Here is the code I currently have for more context.

```
        <div class="container">
    <?php

        $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','', 'cart');
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM products ORDER by id ASC';
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

            if ($result):
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0):
                    while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
                    ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <form method="post" action="index.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $product['id']?>">
                <div class="products">
                    <img src="<?php echo $product['image'];?>" class="img-responsive" />
                    <h4 class="text-muted">
                        <?php echo $product['name'];?>
                    </h4>
                    <h4><?php echo $product['price'];?></h4>
                    <button><a href="<?php echo $product['redirect']?>">Buy</a></button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
                    endwhile;
                endif;
          endif;
            ?>
</div>
```

As you can see the redirect button will redirect the user to the page of the product. Do I have to create a separate page for each product?
Please note that this is my first ever attempt on a website so excuse my ignorance on the subject. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't have to crate a new page for each product. You could and try to give every product in your overview a link like this:

```
<a href="view_product.php?product=<?php echo $product['id'] ?>">Link to product</a>
```

Then create **one** page. This page acts as a placeholder for all the products. We'll call this the product page. On the product page, you can get the data for this specific product like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = "'.$_GET['product'].'"';
```

So now every product has its own page and the query stated above gets all the data on the current product.

#### Note

I'm not using prepared-statement here. This only a small demo on how to get the product. I would strongly advise you to use them! Otherwise, your website is exposed to an SQL-injection!

Comment: this is not `$_GET['id']` it should be `$_GET['product']`